# How to check for a valid guard expression in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I would like to write a macro to check if an Elixir expression is a valid guard :
`defmacro valid_guard?(expr)`

However I could not find anything in the documentation looking for elements to write this piece of code.

I feel like this function should be part of Elixir also but maybe there is a way to plug it in from erlang ?

Comment: what do you mean by valid guard? show some snippets of code of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

One might look into [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir)’s [source code](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.13.3/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L5304-L5360) for [`defguard/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defguard/1) in the first place.

One might technically copy-paste the code calling `:elixir_utils.extract_guards/1` and check for the outcome instead of doing real work, but I am not sure why this would be ever needed.